# Problems with using 'please wait gif image " in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a JSP page with lots of HTML elements and CSS codes and this page appears to be broken till all the code inside document.ready() is complete.So to avoid the initial lag I decided to use a 'Please wait GIF image' while the contents are loading.I came across an excellent code that shows the "please wait symbol" till the page gets loaded.I tested this in one sample JSP and this works fine in Mozilla Firefox browser.But this fails in google chrome.Please help me on this.The code used for the same is given below

```
<style type="text/css">
.modal {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
                url('images/LoadingWait.gif') 
                50% 50% 
                no-repeat;
}

body.loading {
    overflow: hidden;   
}

body.loading .modal {
    display: block;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $body = $("body");
    $body.addClass("loading");
    //important code that takes some time to process 
    alert("sd");
    $body.removeClass("loading");

}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have `alert("sd");` this loading no show on chrome. because firefox wait you press  ok on alert popup and excute `$body.removeClass("loading");` but chrome no wait it excute  `$("body").removeClass("loading")`
 You can replace your code  `$body.removeClass("loading");` with `setTimeout(function(){$("body").removeClass("loading");}, 5000);` to test loading on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `loading` class in `window.load()`. This event will give a better callback after all the images and script are loaded.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("body").removeClass("loading");
});
```

This is just a better way to do the loading functionality.

Comment: I agree to the point.But still it is not working in google chrome.

Comment: Try setting the height of the `.modal` div to `$(window).height()` in the ready event.

Comment: When I used the setTimeout function in place of alert it is found working

Comment: This might be a working solution. But my suggestion is the use of setTimeout() in this case is not recommended. Since the loading of a page may vary on the internet speed which cannot be defined in the setTimeout(). This is just my observation on the loading functionality.

Comment: Yes I totally agree to your point.But for testing purpose in our local server on google chrome browser we can use this